# <div> is being ignored

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two fixed borders(essentially black rectangles) appear in a browser.  One border should be on the far left side of the window and one should be on the far right side.  I have individual CSS classes programmed in the style-sheet(1 for each border).

In the html file, I have both classes called inside separate `<div></div>`.  The problem is that for some reason, only 1 of the 2 will actually display at a time.  Only the 1st(of the2) `<div>` in the program seems to run; if I comment-out `<div>`#1, the other `<div>` will run fine, so I doubt it is a problem with the classes. In addition other `<div></div>` for different things exist in the HTML, that DO run normally.

Below are the 2 classes from the style-sheet:

```
.sidescreenBars1{
border-style: solid;
color:rgb(0,0,0);
background:rgb(0,0,0);
height:100.8%;
width:80px;
margin-left:1489px;}

.sidescreenBars2{
border-style: solid;
color:rgb(0,0,0);
background:rgb(0,0,0);
height:100.8%;
width:80px;
margin-left: 100px;}
```

Below are the classes in the HTML file:

```
<!--Setting the right toolbar(border)on the screen-->  
<div class="sidescreenBars1">
</div>


<!--Setting the left toolbar(border)on the screen-->
<div class="sidescreenBars2">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a Fiddle or a runnable code snippet, so we can test the issue too. Also, do you use Chrome 49 by any chance?

Comment: Why are colour and background both black ? How can you tell which is which ?

Comment: Why not just put a border on the `<body>`?

Comment: Also, if you are positioning "bars"...`margin` is not the way to go.

Comment: They both show up for me (albeit without any height): https://jsfiddle.net/v6femnyf/

Comment: and why no single, full width div with `border-left` and `border-right`? Adding elements just for styling is considered bad practice...

Answer (score 2):

They both appear in my browser (granted they're 1300px apart). Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but I recommend replacing your margins with floats:

```
.sidescreenBars1{
border-style: solid;
color:rgb(0,0,0);
background:rgb(0,0,0);
height:100.8%;
width:80px;
/* margin-left:1489px; */
float:right;
}

.sidescreenBars2{
border-style: solid;
color:rgb(0,0,0);
background:rgb(0,0,0);
height:100.8%;
width:80px;
/* margin-left: 100px;*/
float:left;
}
```

Then wrap them in a 100% width div. That'll keep them on the far edges responsively with different browser widths.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<!--Setting the right toolbar(border)on the screen-->  
<div class="sidescreenBars1">
</div>
<!--Setting the left toolbar(border)on the screen-->
<div class="sidescreenBars2">
</div>
</div>
```